# How to give annotations by using run command in kubernetes to a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I attempted but there is an error..i also see See   **'kubectl run --help' for usage.**
but i can't fix it..

```
kubectl run pod pod4 --image=aamirpinger/helloworld:latest --port=80 --annotaions=createdBy="Muhammad Shahbaz" --restart=Never
```

**Error: unknown flag: --annotaions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`kubectl run`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run) doesn't have an option to set annotations.

Unless you're running a one-off debugging pod, it's usually better practice to write out the full (Deployment) YAML file, commit to source control, and install it using `kubectl apply -f`.  That will let you specify any Kubernetes object property you need to.

Comment: It does now.  `kubectl run --help` shows option `--annotations=[]:`

Answer (score 5):

`kubectl run` supports specifying annotations via the `--annotations` flag that can be specified multiple times to apply multiple annotations.

For example:

```
$ kubectl run --image myimage --annotations="foo=bar" --annotations="another=one" mypod
```

results in the following:

```
$ kubectl get pod mypod -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    foo: bar
    another: one
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned ,there is no --annotations flag for kubectl run command.It is better to write deployment yaml file compared to running using kubectl run command.

However you can add annotations to kubernetes resources using [Kubectl annotate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#annotate) command.All Kubernetes objects support the ability to store additional data with the object as annotations.

Hope this helps.